# Send linux kernel paramters to VM guest in VMware

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, kickstart

I have research a lot about this but I can't find anything that answers my question.

My question is how would I send/pass linux kernel parameters to a VM guest in VMware vsphere (so I don't need to open the console)? Somehow I would like to pass this for exmaple:

```
linux ks=http://ip-addr/ks/kickstart-file.cfg ip=X.X.X.X netmask=X.X.X.X gateway=X.X.X.X dns=X.X.X.X
```

I'm not even sure this is possible. I do know that I can edit the iso file and add the above parameters, but in my case I can't, because I use static IP address when a create a vm.

Is there any tool/API (preferably command line) whatsoever that would let my accomplish this?

Comment: There is no way to directly interact with the bootloader from VMWare. You see, it's not WMVware which passes to kernel command line but the bootloader, usually GRUB or GRUB2.

Comment: You do the same thing you did with bare metal machines: PXE boot.